# Insights Data Retrieval

Tags: facebook

Our Facebook developer app id used for a social bracket game (that we used to measure Insights data from the game) was overridden by the open graph page level Facebook App id (used for Facebook Likes) Because the developer app ID for the bracket game was overridden by the page level app id, the metrics are not showing in Facebook Insights.

Can Facebook provide the developer app Stream Publish data for the # of Stream Publishes, Likes, and Comments based on the page URL/developer app ID if the Insights are not displaying in the Facebook Metrics?  For example, if I provide the developer app id used for this game, can we still pull these metrics if they were not recorded in Insights?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the question - whichever app used to make posts should be able to retrieve insights about those posts, if/whether there was another app ID in use on the domain for another reason shouldn't matter